# Initialized repo on the wrong folder

Tags: github, visual-studio-code, version-control

After selecting Initialize Repo on a particular folder and letting VSCode do its thing, I realized I had a number of items in the folder that I didn't want Repo'd. Rather than move those items out of the folder, however, what I want to do is create a new folder for the stuff I *do* want repo'd and initialize *that*.
How do I go about 'uninitializing' the current folder so that it isn't tracked anymore?

Answer (score 3):

When you create a git repository, a hidden ".git" folder is created in the repository folder. If you want to "uninitialize" it, you just have to delete it.

Comment: Thank you. I'd forgotten that. I very much appreciate the reminder.

Comment: In Windows make sure your explorer shows "hidden files" in the View tab.